# помогите распарсить JSON

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте. Помогите пожалуйста достать "text" из response:

```
    response: {
count: 1,
items: [{
id: 1,
from_id: 390779710,
owner_id: -131534869,
date: 1478433642,
marked_as_ads: 0,
post_type: 'post',
text: 'Абракадабра
Приём
Проба Пера!',
can_delete: 1,
post_source: {
type: 'vk'
},
comments: {
count: 0,
can_post: 1
},
likes: {
count: 0,
user_likes: 0,
can_like: 1,
can_publish: 0
},
reposts: {
count: 0,
user_reposted: 0
}
}]
}
```

Вот так я пытаюсь это сделать, но у меня срабатывает JSONException e.

JSONException: No value for items

Код:

```
     @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
//Do complete stuff
                JSONObject responseObj = response.json;
                try {
                    JSONArray ar = responseObj.getJSONArray("items");
                    JSONObject arJSONObject = ar.getJSONObject(0);
                    String text = arJSONObject.getString("text");
                    Toast.makeText(UserInterface.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                }
```

Comment: В начале предоставьте валидный json

Comment: Проверьте размер `responseObj.getJSONArray("items")` он, похоже пустой

Answer (score 1):

```
 JSONObject responseObj = response.json;
            try {
                JSONObject response = responseObj.getJSONObject("")
                JSONArray ar = responseObj.getJSONArray("items");
                JSONObject arJSONObject = ar.getJSONObject(0);
                String text = arJSONObject.getString("text");
                Toast.makeText(UserInterface.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
            }
```

Может так. json не валидный. прежде чем высылать, проверьте на валидность  [здесь](http://pro.jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Если response - js-объект, можно достать текст просто - `response.items[0].text`